# Why is MPLAB X not compatible with RTOS

Tags: c, rtos, mplab

MPLABX has many simulation features, trouble shooting, and bug testing features that I found very useful while I was writing C code in college. Now that im in industry and the systems are more complicated, Real time Operating systems(RTOS) seem to be common place.

I have not yet been able to integrate these awesome trouble shooting tools in with the RTOS. Is there a quick fix that has just been overlooked? Or is there something more fundamental about the two that do not jive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to prevent RTOS development in MPLABX, lack of any integration features does not prevent use of an RTOS library; it is after all just a library like any other.  What an RTOS does imply however is a slightly more complex runtime and debug environment, and in most cases when you hit a break-point *all* threads are suspended.

What is it you expect from an RTOS integartion?  In cases where such integartion is provided, support varies; some of the possible features include:

- view thread call-stacks
- view status of multiple threads,
- view status kernel objects,
- thread-aware debugging and break-points,
- per-thread CPU load statistics
- timing-graphs of thread execution and context switches.

When an RTOS product comes from a third-party vendor, RTOS integration would have to be by bi-lateral agreement between the two vendors, or where the IDE vendor has provided a documented plug-in architecture for the purpose, and the RTOS vendor or other party has chosen to support it.  There are many RTOS vendors and many IDEs - picking two that work together rather limits your choice to possibly products less that ideally suited to your application or target.

Even IDE's with some level of RTOS integration seldom implement thread-level breakpoints - they require the capability to be built into the kernel (to switch break-points on context switches), not just the IDE or debugger. VxWorks supports that for example, but it does not target PIC.

RTOS integration within an IDE is most common when the IDE, RTOS and often the compiler come from the same vendor; for example Mentor Graphics Nucleus, WindRiver's VxWorks, QSSL's QNX, TI's CCS and DSP/BIOS or Keil's uVision and RTX; none of which target PIC.  Xpress Logic's ThreadX integrates with MPLAB Harmony for PIC32.

Most RTOS / PIC combinations are probably too simple and niche, and the market too fragmented to even bother, and to be honest you are probably not missing much.

Regardless of RTOS awareness in the IDE you can still expect normal source-level symbolic debugger functionality, but will only be able to see non-static local variables for the current thread; this is not quite as restrictive as it may seem; by using breakpoints at the signalling and receiving ends of a thread interaction, you can debug thread interaction behaviour adequately in most cases.

Comment: Very insightful. I was unaware that they the RTOS and IDE has to work together at that level of detail. I was hoping to be able to use the general IDE troubleshooting tools located in the "windows" tab. There are things such as Variables, watches, call stack, breakpoints, stopwatch, and also a simulation feature that does not require hardware to run. From my understanding, non of this is available due to the RTOS that we use.

Comment: @Gascon26 :  I am surprised, and almost certain that you are incorrect and your problem is not what you believe it to be. You should probably specify the RTOS and PIC variant in that case to get a better answer.  I have used MPLAB for dsPIC/PIC24 development in the past using [CMX-Tiny+ and CMX-RTX](http://www.cmx.com/microchip/) without problems.  The debugger does not need to be RTOS aware for that basic level of functionality; the symbol table is the same, and local variable locations are relative to the stack-pointer so having multiple thread stacks is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

MPLABX its just the IDE, the problem its the compiler.
XC16 and XC32 its compatible with some popular RTOS including FreeRTOS, however, the XC8 compiler can't deal with complex RTOS. Its a very buggy compiler and cant generate effective assembly code from advanced pointer expressions.